# RAD Studio XE2 deletes OnClick set in dfm when opening project

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-xe2

We have an application that can be run in Simple or Advanced mode. The difference is what main menu entries are visible. The problem is that RAD Studio XE2 silently deletes the OnClick property value set in the dfm. It points to a procedure hiding some menu items in the Main Menu > File menu.

Steps:
1. A fresh checkout from subversion to a new folder on disk, one that never existed before.
2. Opening the main form's dfm and pas files in notepad++ to ensure that the "OnClick = MenuItem_File1Click" row is there and that procedure MenuItem_File1Click is in interface and implementation of pas file. Yes, everything looks good.
3. Open project in RAD Studio XE2.
4. OnClick property of File menu item in Object Inspector is blank.

We have some other menu items that were handled in FormShow and they work as expected, hidden in Simple mode and visible in Advanced. The workaround was to move the functionality inside the MenuItem_File1Click to FormShow. But I really want to understand why it happened in the first place.

Can anyone explain this behaviour? Has anyone else come across something like this? I tried renaming the procedure to something definitiely not system-like but the IDE removed it anyway.

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is a corrupt file. Can you match all components in the DFM with their definitions in the .pas file? Also: Do you have a lot of form inheritance? Do you maybe use DevExpress TdxBarManager? Can you post your DFM as text here?

Comment: Perhaps inheritance ? ot maybe event handler is from another unit, which gots loaded after the DFM in question loaded, hence at 1st DFM load time the handlers is just not loaded yet and could not be found?

Comment: @Jan Doggen: It could be that dfm corruption somehow is the culprit. I'll look into if all properties in the dfm seem valid. I can't post the dfm here. Form inheritance: no, the main form is just a TForm. TdxBarmanager is not used. No other 3rd party components. Just standard VCL and our own. I'll see if I can recreate it easily by starting with a blank form and then dropping our components on it, one by one. It's a quick and easy test, hopefully I'll find it.

Comment: @Arioch: The procedure appointed as event handler is in the pas file for the form itself.

Comment: 1. Do you have Actions hooked to your Menu and somehow a conflict occurs? 2. What if you put some code back into that onClick event, does it also disappear later?

Comment: @François: 1. Yes, that seems to be it! There are actions set for the same menu item. I was under the impression that it's okay to have both an action and an OnClick if the action does not have an OnExecute. 
2. The procedure contains a few lines of code and is never deleted, that only happens to the OnClick property for the menu item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you hook up your `Menu` (or a `Button`) with an `Action`, then the `Action` is supposed to take over the control of all these properties:
`AutoCheck, Caption, Checked, Enabled, HelpContext, Hint, GroupIndex, Bitmap/ImageIndex, ShortCut, Visible` and in your case **`OnClick/Execute`**.

That's the "raison d'etre" of the Actions in the 1st place.

So if you leave your `Action` without an `Execute` event handler, you are de facto putting `nil` into your Control's `OnClick` event.

And this happens whenever the controls are read from the dfm at the moment the Action specified in the dfm is hooked to the control. Just try to set the OnClick, then switch to View As Text and back (Alt+F12 twice) and your OnClick is gone...

See the VCL source:

```
procedure TMenuItem.ActionChange(Sender: TObject; CheckDefaults: Boolean);
begin
  if Sender is TCustomAction then
    with TCustomAction(Sender) do
    begin
      if not CheckDefaults or (Self.AutoCheck = False) then
        Self.AutoCheck := AutoCheck;
      if not CheckDefaults or (Self.Caption = '') then
        Self.Caption := Caption;
      if not CheckDefaults or (Self.Checked = False) then
        Self.Checked := Checked;
      if not CheckDefaults or (Self.Enabled = True) then
        Self.Enabled := Enabled;
      if not CheckDefaults or (Self.HelpContext = 0) then
        Self.HelpContext := HelpContext;
      if not CheckDefaults or (Self.Hint = '') then
        Self.Hint := Hint;
      if RadioItem and (not CheckDefaults or (Self.GroupIndex = 0)) then
        Self.GroupIndex := GroupIndex;
      if not CheckDefaults or (Self.ImageIndex = -1) then
        Self.ImageIndex := ImageIndex;
      if not CheckDefaults or (Self.ShortCut = scNone) then
        Self.ShortCut := ShortCut;
      if not CheckDefaults or (Self.Visible = True) then
        Self.Visible := Visible;
      if not CheckDefaults or not Assigned(Self.OnClick) then
        Self.OnClick := OnExecute; // <====== use debug dcus and put a break here...
    end;
end;
```

**Update: ... but this should not happen if you have code in the OnClick event.**
This looks like a bug. When the MenuItem is read from the dfm, the parent Form is not yet fully loaded and the OnClick appears as

```
Name            Value
FOnClick    ($3,$6142210)
    Code    $3
    Data    $6142210
```

but `Assigned(FOnClick)` returns `False` !!!!

So `if not CheckDefaults or (@Self.OnClick=nil) then`
would be a better test